# how to setup some condtions using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If am trying to setup few conditions for my website members. below is the scenario that i am trying to acheive.

```
if(upgraded member ) { allowed to cashout }

else (members from these countries){
some conditions here before they can request cashout
}
```

Below is the sample extract of the code that i am using

```
if($member[accounttype] == upgraded ) { $draw=1; } 

elseif ($member[country] == "Pakistan"){
if ($Total >= $Required)  {
                                    $draw=1;
                                   } }
```

I want the countires list to be taken from db
$draw =1 means allowed to cashout, by default its set to 0
Kindly guide.

Comment: What does the database look like, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: `else` dose not support such condition have you used. use `elseif($member[country] == "Pakistan")` instead.

Comment: where is your select statement query?

Comment: @bob brown : database is just one table with countries list. .. I have shown u the sample code that i am using ... i am not getting the idea , how to extract list of countries from the db and use them here.

Comment: @void main : agreed...

Comment: @Naveedasif: It's going to be hard for us to help you without some detail about the database.  Edrich asked about the query you are using.  What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to populate countries list into array from database and then try to compare it and use it according to your requirement. For ex.
if you fetched coutries list like `$country = array('Pakistan', 'China', 'India');`

Now use in_array();

```
if(in_array($member[country], $country)){ 
       if ($Total >= $Required)  {
           $draw=1;
       }
}
```